# Stuck inside Immediately Invoked function (IIFE)

Tags: javascript, function, loops, return, iife

So i have a IIFE as such in my code with a while loop inide. When the loop finished the console.log("Hey") executes but it doesnt come out of the function. Can anyone tell me whats going on?

```
(function () {
       return new Promise(async resolve => {
            while (i <= fcount) {
                i++;
                //some code
            }
            console.log("Hey");
            resolve("done");
       })
}());
```

Comment: What is the value of fcount?

Comment: "doesn't come out of the function" — what does that mean? How can you tell? What did you expect to happen?

Comment: Where is `i` and `fcount` defined?

Comment: Why do you return a promise from an IEFE? And you should [never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)!

Comment: It looks like you are trying to make a `while` loop happen asynchronously. That's not going to work.

Answer (score -1):

When you say

> it doesn't come out of the function

Yes, it comes out of the function returning you a promise.

Just do something like this:

```
(function () {
       return new Promise(resolve => {
            while (i <= fcount) {
                i++;
                //some code
            }
            console.log("Hey");
            resolve("done");
       })
}().then(message => console.log(message)));
```

And you will get `done` in the console.

Another thing, why you use `async` you always need to use `async` with `await`.

You can do something like this:

```
async function whileFunc() {
  const message = await (function () {
       return new Promise(resolve => {
            while (i <= fcount) {
                i++;
                //some code
            }
            console.log("Hey");
            resolve("done");
       })       
  }());

  console.log(message);
}
```

calling `whileFunc` you will get `message` using async/await

Answer (score -1):

I wasn't closing the browser before returning (using puppeteer), hence the program kept running. Thanks everyone for your feedback.